# Zabbix Item Calculation (Memory)

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I want to get the percentage of free Memory on my laptop.
I want to get that info through an item of type: "Calculated".
1. what is the correct syntax for doing that?
2. what am I supposed to put into the "key" parameter while creating the "calculated" item?

This is what i tried so far:
Formula: `last(vm.memory.size[available]) / last(vm.memory.size[total])`
OS: WIN 10
Zabbix: 3.2

Comment: You mentioned what you have tried, but not what happened. Did it work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

2. For calculated items you come up with the key, using the allowed characters - it will only act as an identifier of the item.